# Pointer to a struct as a parameter, members referenced within function produce strange values

Tags: c, pointers, parameters, structure, member

I'm tasked with adding the quick-fit allocation algorithm to MINIX, and as such need to use structures a lot. However, I came accross something for which I cannot find any resources on a solution.

The below code is a quick example I made to demonstrate the issue I have met with.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct some_struct {
    int h_count;
};

void why();

struct some_struct * myStruct;

int main(){ 
    myStruct = (struct some_struct *) malloc(sizeof(struct some_struct));
    myStruct->h_count=0;

    printf("%d\n", myStruct->h_count);
    why(&myStruct);

    return 0;
}

void why(struct some_struct * t_some_struct){
    printf("%d\n", t_some_struct->h_count);
}
```

The output of the *printf* in the function *why* is different from the output given in main. The value printed by *why* is a seemingly random number that changes every time the program is ran.

Output:

```
0
7870280
Press any key to continue . . .`
```

The 7870280 changes on every run. I would assume it is printing some kind of memory value or something, but that's just a guess as I have no idea really.

As such, I thought I'd ask here for the benefit of others alongside myself:

- Why does this occur?
- Is my syntax the issue here?
- How do I use a pointer to a structure as a parameter for some function, then reference the given structure's members in the scope of the function? (I'd like to use h_count for t_some_struct as 0)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `why` expects a pointer whereas you are passing a pointer to pointer. Call as
`why(myStruct);` (by the way, `myStruct` is a global variable, so passing is a bit superfluous here). Rest of your accessing the struct member is fine.

Not directly related but some general suggestions:

1) Use standard prototype for `main()` such as `int main(int argc, char*argv[])`
2) Casting the result of malloc is needless and [error-prone.](http://c-faq.com/malloc/cast.html)

Comment: This solved my question instantly. Thank you so much, I feel like such a goon!

Comment: Theres a 3 minute timeout on accepting questions, trust me, I'm trying. EDIT: Done :) Thanks again

Comment: You don't have to though. It's your *choice* :)